# Why does mobile safari only show a loader and then just a black rectangle when playing a youtube embed via javascript on an iphone?

Tags: iphone, youtube, mobile-safari

I'm trying to show a youtube video that is started using javascript. This is how the video-object is instatiated:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '720',
        width: '1280',
        html5: 0,
        videoId: 'i8IXMGHpGBk',
        playerVars: {'modestbranding': 1, 'controls': 1,'showinfo': 0, 'rel': 0 },
        events: {
            'onStateChange': function(e) {
                if (e.data === 0) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(".quizwrapper").offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    document.getElementById('first').focus();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm later playing the video like this:

```
    if(player){
        player.playVideo();
        console.log(player);
    }
```

This works in all four mayor broswers and chrome for android. But in safari on iphone, it looks as though the video starts to load (the youtube spinning balls) and after that just a black rectangle.

I get no errors in inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [YouTube iFrame API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) which takes you to the [Apple Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html):

> **Warning**: To prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at the user’s expense, embedded media cannot be played automatically
>   in Safari on iOS—the user always initiates playback. A controller is
>   automatically supplied on iPhone or iPod touch once playback is
>   initiated, but for iPad you must either set the `controls` attribute
>   or provide a controller using JavaScript.